# How to tell theme customizer to save setting in my option table?

Tags: theme-customizer

Default customizer is saving the options inside

```
theme_mods_themename
```

but my I am using Unyson options framework and my options reside here

```
fw_theme_settings_options:themename
```

I am able to use this to control the view change

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
 fw_get_db_settings_option('footer_branding'),
  array(
    'default'   => fw_get_db_settings_option('footer_branding'),
  )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(  
  'footer_branding',
  array(  
    'section'   => 'site_tab',  
    'label'     => 'Branding',  
    'type'      => 'textarea',  
    'settings'  => fw_get_db_settings_option('footer_branding')
  )
);
```

the change and option work visually but customizer is saving it in its own table and on reload it is reading it from that table again.

Any help is appreciated.

As requested more info ,

Unyson is saving options in serialized array inside the db ,  and extracting them like this

```
fw_get_db_settings_option('footer_branding')
```

which is replacement for

```
get_option('footer_branding')
```

setting option goes like this

```
 fw_set_db_settings_option('footer_branding')
```

here is detail info about it

http://manual.unyson.io/en/latest/helpers/php.html#database

Comment: That's a very custom problem you are facing (due to the framework). Can you update your question with the code necessary to understand what's going on under the hood?

Comment: @kaiser, thnx for reply , I updated the info with unyson db settings

Comment: Benn, this only shows the function name. No one can know whats going on behind that.

Comment: @Benn you probably have to use `https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_update_option_%28option_name%29`